# What is the difference between `AS base` and `AS build` in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to know the difference between

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
```

and

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
```

Could you explain the difference between `AS base` and `AS build`?

Here is a default Dockerfile generated by Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no functional difference, it's only a name for build stage. Stage is a part of the dockerfile starting at `FROM` keyword and ends before the next `FROM` keyword.

The image built in this stage of dockerfile will be later accessible using that name.

For example, names `foo` and `bar`

```
FROM image AS foo
...
...

FROM foo AS bar
RUN touch /example
...
...

FROM foo
COPY --from=bar /example /var/example
```

> Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding AS name to the FROM instruction. The name can be used in subsequent FROM and COPY --from=<name|index> instructions to refer to the image built in this stage.
>
> - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

It was added in 17.05 for multistage builds, more on that: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/